# Stop eclipse from resetting root context when Maven->Update Project / MANIFEST.MF file not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, manifest.mf

I am building an application using Eclipse, Maven, Tomcat, and Spring Framework.

Every time I need to "Clean ..." or "Clean Work Directory" for Tomcat, I also end up having to use the "Maven->Update Project" tool in order to stop the MANIFEST.MF file not found error. After that, I always have to update my context root to "/" instead of the project name.

Is there anyway that I can stop eclipse from resetting context root? Or is there anyway to stop the MANIFEST.MF not found error?

Maybe there's a better way to manage root context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successful Maven Build, Refresh the Root Project beofre deploying your app to tomcat server

Comment: I apologize for the delay, there you go (: